# Do accepted suggested edits on deleted questions (so +2/-2 rep) still count towards +1000 rep limit?

Tags: support, reputation, suggested-edits, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

If you suggest an edit on a question and that edit is accepted resulting in a +2 rep change. If further down the line that question is then deleted resulting in a -2 rep change, does it also result in -2 rep change on your +1000 rep limit for suggested edits.

I'm sure it does but thought I'd clarify.

Comment: @gnat I did first read that post but after reading "When a suggested edit is approved, the user who suggested it gets +2 reputation. The regular daily reputation cap applies, and the total cap is 1,000. Like any other reputation, the +2 is deleted if the edited post is ever deleted." I still wasn't sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a post is [deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/165773), it is as if the rep was never added to your total in the first place. All that is left are two entries in your history log to show that you did once gain those points and when the gain was cancelled again; these only show up if you check the `show removed posts` tickbox.

As such, it won't count towards the reputation limit set for suggested edits.

Answer (score 2):

When a question gets deleted, the reputation gained for suggested edits will be taken off.

So, yes, it will result in -2 rep change. At that point, it would no longer count towards the 1000 rep limit.