# Influence of removal/migration of posts in suggested edits

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits, deleted-posts

I edited a question and got 2 reps and then after 2 days that post got removed and I got -2 reps.

I can accept that, but the no. of successful edits also decreased by 1. As one of my suggested edit was approved by reviewers, it should be in the no. of successful edits.

I just want to know, What is the reason for decreasing the number of successful edits during removal/migration of those posts?

Comment: Was the question/answer you edited was deleted ?

Comment: you place more value on number of suggested edits than rep?

Comment: @Apurv, yes some of them are migrated

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do accepted suggested edits on deleted questions (so +2/-2 rep) still count towards +1000 rep limit?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163390/do-accepted-suggested-edits-on-deleted-questions-so-2-2-rep-still-count-towa)

Comment: @gnat That asks about rep. This asks about edit count. How is it a duplicate ?

Comment: @AshRj agree, it's not a dupe. Unfortunately, [deletion faq post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/165773) says nothing on that, either